# How should a 4x3 closet bend be installed in concrete?

Tags: plumbing, concrete, toilet

Should the top of the 4" inlet be flush with the top of the concrete or should it sit above or below the concrete? Should it be wrapped with a foam sill plate gasket or something similar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that you are using ABS or PVC pipe and fittings, the inlet of the 4 x 3 closet bend should be flush or below the finished grade of the concrete floor. You do not want the fitting's hub to be proud of the floor, as that will prevent the toilet flange from being installed to the floor level.

Typically, we install a piece of vertical 4” pipe into the inlet of the 4 x 3 closet bend so that the pipe extends past the finished floor level. Then, after the concrete is poured and when installing the toilet flange, we cut the pipe flush with the floor and use a 4” inside pipe toilet flange.

Regarding covering the pipe, it is best practice to wrap any drainage pipe and fittings encased in concrete with a foam sill plate gasket to allow for separation between the concrete and the pipe/fittings.

Comment: Is there no concern about cover?

Comment: Ideally, you want the top of the pipe to be below the bottom of the concrete. However, I’ve seen many installations that, due to the elevation you are given to start with and the required grade to get to where you are going, the pipe at the furriest end is up into the concrete. This is not a big issue in a residential basement but would be a concern in a location subject to vehicle traffic load.

Comment: Furriest end???

Comment: @Huesmann, sorry, furthest.